# C++ winapi elevation

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com

I'm developing windows explorer namespace extension. My application is a dynamic library loaded and used by explorer.exe at some time. I need my DLL to create files in C:\ and sometimes in other locations which need elevation to perform such operations.

How can I perform such elevation and create file at C:\ for example ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, is there such a manifest-feature for DLLs?

Comment: I thought so. So this is not an option for the OP's DLL.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4337793/1015327) sums it up pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code runs inside another process it is at the mercy of the elevation state of that process. If that process does not run elevated, and explorer does not, then your code in your DLL cannot execute elevated.

Your solution therefore is to create another process to perform the tasks which require elevation. Do that using one of these methods:

- Specify the `requireAdministrator` option for `requestedExecutionLevel` in the application manifest.
- Start the process using `ShellExecuteEx` with the `runas` verb.
- Put the code to be elevated in a COM object and use the COM elevation moniker.

Comment: An alternative option is to implement the task requiring elevation as a separate COM object (a namespace extension is itself a COM object, so this would be a more natural solution for a COM developer) and then use the [COM Elevation Moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx) to instantiate the task object when needed. No UAC manifest needed.

Comment: That's a good point. The com approach gives the cleanest way to communicate also.